# KDE Hotkey-Volumecontrol stopped working

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, kubuntu

After installing a fresh Kubuntu (15.04) the hotkeys for volume-control were working out of the box. (Also making some nice "blob"-sound when I used them)

I had to install a few codecs and other stuff and eventually the hotkeys don't work any more. I see the volume-control line increasing and decreasing depending on the button I press but no changes happen. (Also the "blob"-sound is gone)

I tried to assign the shortcuts to different programs but this just made it worse. Now it's back to default but I can't actually control the volume.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I got more channels and the wrong one was selected...

Right Click on the Symbol --> Select Master Channel. And confirming by entering. With double-click it didn't work (tried it before). With enter everything is smooth again